# Writing list in CSV to create a model file

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x, coordinates

I have this CSV that I have to modify using Python.
The number of files varies each time. The input CSV files i have are just a list of coordinates (x, y, z) and i have to modify the file into a 'model' which contains the same coordinates but also some information/headers.

The model looks like this :

```
Number | 1    |      |

Head   | N    |  E   | El

Begin  | list | list | list

       |   .  |  .   |  .
       |   .  |  .   |  .
       |   .  |  .   |  .
       |   .  |  .   |  .
End    |   .  |  .   |  .
       |   .  |  .   |  .  
BeginR |  Ok  |      |
EndR   |      |      |
```

The dots are the coordinates that are in the lists.
So far I've managed to write almost everything.

What's left is to write the **Begin** and the **End** in the first column.
Because the size of the list varies, I have difficulties to place it where they should be : Begin at the same line with the first coordinates and End at the second to last coordinate line.

This is my **updated** code :

```
        for i in ficList:
            with open(i, newline='') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';')
                next(reader) # skip the header
                for row in reader:
                    coord_x.append(row[0]) # X
                    coord_y.append(row [1]) # Y
                    coord_z.append(row[2]) # Z

            list_list = [coord_x, coord_y, coord_z] # list of coordinates
            len_x = len(coord_x) # length of list

            with open(i, 'w', newline='') as fp:
                writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ';')
                writer.writerow(['Number', number])
                writer.writerow(['Head','N', 'E', 'El'])
                for l in range(len_x):
                    if l == 0:
                         writer.writerow(['Begin',list_list[0][l], list_list[1][l], list_list[2][l]]) 
                    if l == len_x-2 :
                         writer.writerow(['End',list_list[0][l], list_list[1][l], list_list[2][l]])
                writer.writerow(['',list_list[0][l], list_list[1][l], list_list[2][l]]) # write the coordinates
                writer.writerow(['BeginR', 'Ok'])
                writer.writerow(['EndR'])
                coord_x.clear() # empty list x
                coord_y.clear() # empty list y
                coord_z.clear() # empty list z
```

Comment: What is the current output you are getting from your code?

Comment: @AnandSKumar The output is a CSV document which looks almost the same as the model I'm trying to get but without the words `Begin`and Ènd`. It's the only thing left I can't manage to write automatically using Python.

Comment: Found it, using a well placed `if`statement. But it writes the line twices..

Comment: Can you update the latest code you are using in the question, Let me take a look

Comment: I did (it's in the `for l in range(len_x)` loop. Thanks !

Comment: So your issue is solved? If not, can you also post a small example of how your data currently looks like?

Comment: I am guessing no, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off to define the row labels in advance in a map, then look them up for each row. Also list_list is not really needed, you should just stick to the separate vectors:

```
...
with open(i, 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerow(['Number', number])
    writer.writerow(['Head','N', 'E', 'El'])

    row_label_map = {0:'Begin',len_x-2:'End'}
    for l in range(len_x):
        row_label = row_label_map.get(l,"")
        writer.writerow([row_label, coord_x[l], coord_y[l], coord_z[l]])

    writer.writerow(['BeginR', 'Ok'])
    writer.writerow(['EndR'])
```

...

Also you don't need to clear the vectors coord_x etc. afterwards as they will be deleted when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

With your latest code, I am guessing the issue is because you are first writing the line with `BEGIN` tag and then without it, move the logic into a `if..elif..else` part -

```
for l in range(len_x):
    if l == 0:
        writer.writerow(['Begin',list_list[0][l], list_list[1][l], list_list[2][l]]) 
    elif l == len_x-2 :
        writer.writerow(['End',list_list[0][l], list_list[1][l], list_list[2][l]])
    else:
        writer.writerow(['',list_list[0][l], list_list[1][l], list_list[2][l]]) # write the coordinates
```

Comment: sorry typo - `elif` .

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like it would be easier to first modify the input CSV to include and extra column that has the Begin and End tags with `sed` like this:

```
sed -e 's/^/,/' -e '1s/^/Begin/' -e '$ s/^/End/' -e 's/^,/ ,/' test.csv
```

Then you can simply print the columns as they are without having to add logic for when to add the additional tags in python.   This assumes that the input CSV is called `test.csv`

Comment: I've never heard of/used sed so i'll have a look at it to understantd what you wrote.
But i don't think i can modify the input CSV because the structure is different than the output i would like to have. The input is just three columns of coordinates.